# How do I add event listener to document changes in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I can add a watch property to a input form. But what if user presses a key. I want print the key press when the user is on the page.

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
            alert(String.fromCharCode(event.which));
        });
```

But how do I add the check for keypresses in vue?

Comment: i think this is what you want? https://vuejs.org/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers

Comment: @DonaldWu In the above case the event listener is on click button. What I want is the that the invent listener should be on the root document.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options for registering the global event listener.

---

If you have another Vue Instance on your document's root you could use custom events.

Add to your main instance:

```
<body @keydown="this.$emit('onkeydown')">...</body>
```

And to your nested instance:

```
<my-component v-on:onkeydown="alert(String.fromCharCode(event.which));"></my-component>
```

This emits a global event which is caught by your nested instance. If you want to know more about custom events click [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html).

---

If there is no instance on your `body` element you can just create an event listener on the document when your Vue instance is created ([Example](https://jsfiddle.net/hzsaLej2/)):

```
  methods: {
    onkeydown(e) {
      alert(String.fromCharCode(event.which));
    }
  },

  created() {
    document.onkeydown = this.onkeydown;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**html**

```
<div id="test">
  <input v-on:keyup="say()">Say hi</input>
</div>
```

**js**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#test',
  methods: {
    say: function (e) {
      alert(e.keyCode)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I have already done this, but I don't want the input element. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40283406/how-to-capture-any-keypress-event-in-vuejs-without-using-input-element)

Comment: did u try to put the event in body? ``<body id="test" v-on:keyup="say()">``

Comment: But my body tag is outside the `<div id="app" >` . will your method work?

Comment: you can try...I did not use vue before